Triangles in SL_d/SO_d
I was playing around with $X_d$ be the symmetric space of $SL_d (\mathbb{R})$, and found the following (vague) question:

Given $p,q,r \in X_d$, under which conditions $p,q,r$ lie in a totally geodesic copy of $\mathbb{H}^2$?

More precisely, we know that $q = e^{x}.p$, and $r = e^{y}.p$, for $x,y \in \mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{p}$ the eigenspace decomposition for the Cartan involution (or traceless self-adjoint matrices with the correct identifications). Then the question is equivalent to determine when are $x,y$ in an $\mathfrak{sl}_2 (\mathbb{R})$ triplet. Since both $x,y$ are semisimple elements, I'm confused about when this happens.
A further question that I find interesting is:

Given a geodesic $\gamma$ on $X$, how many copies of $\mathbb{H}^2$ contain it?

This may depend on whether the geodesic is regular or not.
Thanks beforehand!

What exactly do you mean by $\mathbb H^2$? What constant value of curvature do you assume and, accordingly, how do you normalize the metric on your symmetric space?

@MoisheKohan great point! I mean an $\mathbb{H}^2$ tangent to the planes with minimal sectional curvature (now that I think of it, do you have other $\mathbb{H}^2$ w. other sectional curvatures?)

Yes, of course there will be.
